# Как скопировать значение кнопки?

Tags: html, css

Такой вопрос: как мне скопировать само значение кнопки?
Т.е.:

```
<input id="knop" name="nomer_vagona" type="submit" value="<?=$item->num ?>" />
```

Значение `value` нужно копировать.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('knop').value
```

Comment: что-то не работает)

Comment: из такого комментария понять ничего не возможно:)

http://jsfiddle.net/KmvaC/ - вот все работает. 

Что именно и как у вас не работает?